# JAVASCRIPT - Dynamic Createt Div's won't take the given style ( width & height )

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic

I'm trying to create some divs, with user input values like amount and size.

In my situation now the divs are createt but in the outoput html ( firefox -> show selected source ) they don't have taken the given attribute like '.style.top' , '.style.left', '.width' ( or .style.width ) and '.height' ( or .style.height ).

the first createt div has -> style="top:0px; left:0px; . . ."
the secont one only has -> style="top:0px; . . "       // the 'left' attrib doesnt appear anymore
and all the following divs doesnt have top or left.

also none of the createt divs have been taken the width and the height.

here is my code, its verry simple and basic, but i cant figure out the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Container Pattern Generator</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {

        }

        .div_container {
            position:absolute;
            border:solid 1px #000;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generate() {
            var boxSize = document.getElementById("txt_boxSize").value;
            var width = document.getElementById("txt_width").value;
            var height = document.getElementById("txt_height").value;
            for( var i = 1; i <= height; i++ ) {
                for( var ii = 1; ii <= width; ii++ ) {
                    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "div_container_" + i + "_" + ii);
                    newDiv.setAttribute("class", "div_container");
                    newDiv.width = boxSize + "px";
                    newDiv.height = boxSize + "px";
                    newDiv.style.top = ( i - 1 ) * boxSize;
                    newDiv.style.left = ( ii - 1 ) * boxSize;
                    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = getRandColor();
                    document.getElementById("div_main").appendChild( newDiv );
                    alert("ok");
                }
            }
        }

        function getRandColor() {
            var array = new Array( "#FF0000", "#FF8000", "#FF0000", "#01DF01", "#FF0000", "#0404B4", "#FF8000", "#F2F2F2" );
            return array[ randNum( 0, array.length ) ];
        }

        function randNum( min, max ) {
            var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 1 + max - min ) ) + min;
            return num;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Width : <input type="text" value="2" id="txt_width" style="width:50px;"/> - Height : <input type="text" value="2" id="txt_height" style="width:50px;"/> - Box Size : <input type="text" value="40" id="txt_boxSize" style="width:50px;"/> - <input type="button" value="Generate" onClick="generate();"/></p>
    <div id="div_main" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#999;">
    </div>
</body>
```

you can just copy the cote to a blank html file and see whyt i mean.

thx for all your help. g.r. Ace

**EDIT:**

the problem is 100% inside the loop, where the div's are created.

in the first version i've simply hardcoded the amount of the divs ( blank divs )
but now it sould be dynamic.. and the problem begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, the problem is within your loop. The main problem is that you should be appending these styles using `setAttribute`. Also, that your top and left definitions need to have "px" on them, and your width and height are not using the right hook. They could be used if you tried `newDiv.style.width` or `newDiv.style.width`.  However, I think it is best practice to stick with `setAttribute`. See this example:

All of this:

```
newDiv.width = boxSize + "px";
newDiv.height = boxSize + "px";
newDiv.style.top = ( i - 1 ) * boxSize;
newDiv.style.left = ( ii - 1 ) * boxSize;
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = getRandColor();
```

can become this:

```
var divTop = parseInt((i - 1)*boxSize) + "px;";
var divLeft = parseInt((ii - 1)*boxSize) + "px;";
newDiv.setAttribute("style",
  "top: " + divTop + 
  "left: " + divLeft + 
  "width: " + boxSize + 
  "px;height: " + boxSize + "px;background-color:"+getRandColor()+ ";");
```

Comment: it works for me. thx for the answer. anyway i'm still wondering why the "popular" way doesn't work..

Comment: @Ace - see my edit at the top for an explanation of that. Pretty much just a simple slip in your syntax. Missing `.style.width` and `"px;"`. Sometimes I have noticed that using `.style.width` doesn't work as well as using setAttribute though, which is why I suggested using it and I use it exclusively when doing things like this.

Comment: yeah , allready imagine that now ^^ i should have take some sleep instead of working all night long X_X thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You gave invalid attribute values. This is because you are setting **newDiv.height** and **newDiv.width** instead of **newDiv.style.height** and **newDiv.style.width** to a non-numeric value. Fill the values into style attributes, with suffices, and it'll work.

Also, if you try modularizing your code a bit, it may be easier to debug/maintain and for others to understand.

**EDIT**

Meaning I'd try this (no refactoring):

```
newDiv.style.width = boxSize + "px";
newDiv.style.height = boxSize + "px";
newDiv.style.top = (( i - 1 ) * boxSize) + "px";
newDiv.style.left = (( ii - 1 ) * boxSize) + "px";
```

Comment: I've modified it to newDiv.style.width = boxsize + "px" and it definitely worked. At least it seemed to as I'm not sure what it was meant for, but I managed to get randomly colored boxes with the size I supplied. Whenever you give the .style.something values, they have to have the "px" suffix (e.g. .style.top), while the regular DOM attributes won't accept them.

Comment: yeah i already imagine that i've forgot the + "px" for top and left value. but it's solved already